# How can I overwrite and append data to the same file multiple times in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a "clients.txt" file where I have a list of emails. I try to run a program for sending emails where I chose a number of emails to use from the file, in that case the number is 2. After I use the two emails I want to overwrite "clients.txt" without them. The problem is when I try to run the code just for one single time every thing is working! but if I make a loop something is wrong. Looking forward to see any help from you guys. Thanks! I add the code bellow. PS: Sorry for my bad english!

```
function readEmails(){
    const fs = require('fs');
    clients_list = fs.readFileSync('clients.txt', 'utf8').split('\n');
    let filtered = clients_list.filter(function (el) {
        return el != null && el != '';
    });
    return filtered
}
function dump_array(arr, file){
    let fs = require('fs');
    let file = fs.createWriteStream(file);
    file.on('error', function(err) { /* error handling */ });
    arr.forEach(function(v) { file.write(v + '\n'); });
    file.end();
}

while_var = 0;
while (while_var < 2){
    while_var ++;
    let all_clients = readEmails();
    let selected_clients = [];
    if (all_clients.length > 0){
        selected_clients = all_clients.splice(0,2);
        dump_array(all_clients, 'clients.txt');
        console.log(selected_clients);
    }else{
        console.log('No more clients')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');

function readEmails(){
    const clients_list = fs.readFileSync('clients.txt', 'utf8').split('\n');
    const filtered = clients_list
        // clear false, 0 and undefined too
        .filter(el => !!el) 
        // remove extra spaces and \r symbols
        .map(el => el.trim()); 
    return filtered;
}
function dump_array(arr, file){
    // Here you need sync method. 
    fs.writeFileSync(file, arr.join('\n')); 
    // And here was 'already declared' error in orginal code
}

let while_var = 0;
while (while_var++ < 2){
    let all_clients = readEmails();
    let selected_clients = [];
    if (all_clients.length > 0){
        selected_clients = all_clients.splice(0,2);
        dump_array(all_clients, 'clients.txt');
        console.log(selected_clients);
    }else{
        console.log('No more clients')
    }
}
```

Comment: On every loop I'm looking to take two clients from the `clients.txt` and to overwrite the file without them. So I need to put the `let all_clients = readEmails();` inside the loop because every time will be a different `clients.txt` content. The code you provide is not good.

Comment: I'm looking to have on every loop two new clients in `let selected_clients = []` and to overwrite the `clients.txt' without them.

Comment: @popescuandrei ok, i fix it now

Comment: @popescuandrei I fixed the code and check it on my machine, work fine